# В 2D игре необходимо нарисовать траекторию полета объекта, зная угол броска и силу/скорость броска

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю 2D платформер, есть персонаж, который должен бросать гранату.
Сейчас бросок гранаты реализован так:

```
Vector3 grenatePosition = transform.position;
grenatePosition.y += 2.0F;
float Grx = 20.0f;
float Gry = 20.0f;
Vector2 throwForce = new Vector2(Grx, Gry);
GameObject grenade = Instantiate(grenatePrefab, grenatePosition, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
grenade.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(throwForce * 0.5f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

То есть задается некоторая сила throwForce, которая прикладывается к гранате (начальная позиция гранаты = позиции игрока).

Угол можно найти через Grx и Gry (арктангенс).

Возможно, можно реализовать бросок не через силу, а через скорость (пробовал сделать, но не получилось в 2D).

Буду крайне благодарен, если поможете сделать отрисовку траектории (LineRenderer)

Нашел такое вот решение, но здесь рисуется через конечную позицию, которая в моем случае не известна:

https://habr.com/ru/post/490926/

Как найти конечную позицию или нарисовать, зная силу и угол?

буду очень благодарен, уже долго мучаюсь...

Comment: можете для простоты считать, что траектория параболическая и пренебречь сопротивлением воздуха. Начальный вектор известен (угол/скорость броска и ускорение свободного падения), остальное дело техники. В каком-нибудь учебнике физики уже наверняка даже есть готовая формула

Comment: @Эникейщик Я так понимаю, массу и силу тяжести  брать равными значениям в Rigidbody2D? И начальная сила броска в моем случае будет равна 0.5f с углом броска 45 градусов?

Comment: как-то так, да.

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо, попробую...

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался.
Есть возможность узнать скорость:

```
Vector2 v2Velocity = rb.velocity;
```

или, если нужно числовое значение

```
var speed = rb.velocity.magnitude;`
```

Здесь rb - `Rigidbody2D rb = ?.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`
Применяем это сразу после реализации броска и получаем начальные значения.

Дальше уже понятно, можно использовать формулы из баллистики)